# Redux Saga returning API data but coming up undefined when trying to grab nested elements inside the API object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

This is my first time using Sagas, so forgive me if I have set things up incorrectly (I usually use middleware thunks but trying something new)

Here is my saga:

```js
import { call, put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { apiLoaded, apiLoadingError } from 'containers/App/actions'
import { RUN_CURR_DOGS_SAGA } from 'containers/HomePage/constants'
import { displayCurrDogs } from 'containers/HomePage/actions'

import request from 'utils/request'

export function* getRunInfo() {
  const requestURL = `http://kennel-staging.herokuapp.com/api/v1/reservations/current`

  try {
    // Call our request helper (see 'utils/request')
    const results = yield call(request, requestURL)
    yield put(displayCurrDogs(results))
    yield put(apiLoaded(results))
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(apiLoadingError(err))
  }
}

export default function* runInfoSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(RUN_CURR_DOGS_SAGA, getRunInfo)
}
```

My actions:

```js
import { DISPLAY_CURR_DOGS, RUN_CURR_DOGS_SAGA } from './constants'

export function displayCurrDogs(runInfo) {
  return {
    type: DISPLAY_CURR_DOGS,
    runInfo,
  }
}

export function runInfoSagaWatcher() {
  return {
    type: RUN_CURR_DOGS_SAGA,
  }
}
```

My reducers:

```js
import { fromJS } from 'immutable'

import { DISPLAY_CURR_DOGS } from './constants'

export const initialState = fromJS({
  runInfo: false,
})

function homeReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DISPLAY_CURR_DOGS:
      return state.set('runInfo', action.runInfo)
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default homeReducer
```

And finally my container:

```js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { compose } from 'redux'
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect'
import Wrapper from './Wrapper'

import { DAEMON } from 'utils/constants'
import injectReducer from 'utils/injectReducer'
import injectSaga from 'utils/injectSaga'
import { makeSelectLoading, makeSelectError } from 'containers/App/selectors'
import BookingForm from 'components/BookingForm'
import Loading from 'components/Loading'
import { makeSelectRunInfo } from './selectors'
import messages from './messages'
import reducer from './reducer'
import saga from './saga'
import { runInfoSagaWatcher } from './actions'

export class HomePage extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatchSaga } = this.props
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatchSaga()
    }, 0)
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props
    console.log(data)
    if (!data) {
      return <Loading />
    } else {
      console.log(data[0])
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Helmet>
          <title>Home Page</title>
          <meta
            name="HomePage with relevant info"
            content="Content explaining current dogs in the Kennel"
          />
        </Helmet>
        <Wrapper>
          <BookingForm />
          <FormattedMessage {...messages.header} />
        </Wrapper>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  dispatchSaga: () => dispatch(runInfoSagaWatcher()),
})

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  loading: makeSelectLoading(),
  error: makeSelectError(),
  data: makeSelectRunInfo(),
})

const withConnect = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)

const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'home', reducer })
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'home', saga, mode: DAEMON })

export default compose(
  withReducer,
  withSaga,
  withConnect,
)(HomePage)

HomePage.propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.bool,
  error: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.bool]),
  data: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.bool]),
  dispatchSaga: PropTypes.func,
}
```

Currently, in the render, I can console.log data and see the array of objects that is returned from the API. However, the WEIRD issue is inside the else statement, data[0] is coming up undefined, even tho it contains nested objects, as I can see from the first console log of only data.

I've tried wrapping it in a try catch, and a setTimeOut() but both of those left me with the same result of undefined.

Any insight on where I went wrong would be appreciated! Again, I am inexperienced using Sagas

Comment: I think ˋdata ˋ is not an array, but an object with a property ˋdata ˋ, which holds an array. So the way to access your run info is actually ˋdata.data[0]ˋ

Comment: could you attach the log output to verify its an array?